# Can't input asterisk to my Java program in PowerShell

Tags: java, powershell

I wrote a simple calculator in Java that takes 2 numbers and an operator as parameters. When the number of parameters is not 3, I throw an IllegalArgumentException. I call it writing

```
java Main 3 * 7
```

in PowerShell. Any time I use the * asa an operator, I get the `IllegalArgumentException`. It works fine with "+", "-" and "/". I tried using escape characters when writing the *. The only thing that happened is when I wrote

```
java Main 3 ´* 9
```

I got no output at all. Every other time I get the exception.

Comment: `java --% main 3 * 9`

Comment: Ever thought about what happened when you enter `del *` in Microsoft Windows Powershell?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I tried it but I get the exception like before (not 3 parameters)

Comment: @tquadrat Yes, but can I input * as a string in powershell?

Comment: In most shells – including PowerShell – the asterisk is a special character that is expanded to all the files in the current folder. Is described in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Start-Process java -ArgumentList 'Main','3','*','9' -NoNewWindow
```

This will start the java program and show output in console.

Comment: I get the same exception this way

Answer (score 0):

Try `java Main 3 "*" 9` – it worked on my `bash` shell, should work on PowerShell, too.

Comment: I get the same exception :(

Comment: You used the quotes (double-quotes, ") around the asterisk? Really? If so, PowerShell differs from bash obviously much more than I ever expected …